# Memory Leaks instruments warning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode-instruments

[image: Leaks will report false positives while the environment variable NSZombiesEnabled is active]

I have removed the NSZombiesEnabled from Debug run time argument in the environment variables.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Xcode? Clean the project? Restart your mac?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I even have tried to run the instruments on my other mac machine, but no luck. Same issue there too

Comment: @Jagadeeshwar hi i am facing same issue have you found solution for it

Comment: @Jagadeeshwar looks like if we try to use iOS7 device with xcode 4.6 its giving that warning, i have tried on iOS6 device and its worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my project neither option Enable Zombie Objects was checked, but when I disable the option "Use the Run action's argumments ... " worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to turn off the NSZombieEnabled in the Profile scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects is set to off?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was turned off